# Express more formally

Tags: formality

How can I say these sentences in a more formal way?

- Glad you're OK
- Great news , got the job
- Sorry, can't make it next Saturday
- it's still ok for Friday?
- Thanks loads!
- can't wait to see you

Comment: Using full sentences would be a start! :) (e.g. the word 'I' seems to be missing a lot…)

Comment: it's from a student book, there are no full sentences of this :) they ask to write this short sentences more formal in a letter or email.

Comment: I didn't mean that you made the mistake when copying it in, just that this would be the first step to take — what have you tried so far? Are you just asking people here to do the exercise for you?

Comment: No, that is not why i posted this, I have an exam tomorrow about this subject.

Comment: OK, so if you don't want people to just give you the answers, you should expand your question to elaborate on what it is that you're having trouble with & what you've tried already.

Comment: thanks loads! = I'm so thankful good start?

Comment: can't wait to see you = I look forward to hearing from you in the near future

Comment: We do not do ghostwriting here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm glad all's well with you.

I've some excellent news, I got the job!

I'm very sorry but I shall not be able to join you next Saturday.

Is everything still alright for Friday?

Thank you very much!

I can't wait till we meet.